# How to correctly use a nested class of a template class?

Tags: c++, nested, template-classes

all!
I am trying to implement a simple template class binary search tree.
I run into a couple problem with the definitions of functions.
The following is my BST class code

```
#ifndef BINARY_SEARCH_TREE_H
#define BINARY_SEARCH_TREE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class BST
{
    struct TreeNode {
        TreeNode* left;
        TreeNode* right;
        T value;
    };

    //member functions
    void destroyTree(TreeNode* leaf);
    void insert(T key, TreeNode* leaf);
    TreeNode* search(T key, TreeNode* leaf);
    void printInOrder(TreeNode* leaf);
    void printPreOrder(TreeNode* leaf);
    void printPostOrder(TreeNode* leaf);

    //memebr variables
    TreeNode* root;
public:

    enum Traversal { INORDER, PREORDER, POSTORDER };

    BST();
    BST(T key);
    ~BST();

    void insert(T key);
    TreeNode* search(T key);
    void printTree(T option);
    void destroyTree();
};

template <class T>
BST<T>::BST()
{
    root = NULL;
};

template <class T>
BST<T>::BST(T key)
{
    root = new TreeNode;
    root->left = NULL;
    root->right = NULL;
    root->value = key;
};

template <class T>
BST<T>::~BST()
{
    destroyTree();
};

template <class T>
void BST<T>::destroyTree(TreeNode* leaf)
{
    if (leaf->left != NULL) destroyTree(leaf->left);
    if (leaf->right != NULL) destroyTree(leaf->right);
    delete leaf;
    leaf = nullptr;
};

template <class T>
void insert(T key, BST<T>::TreeNode* leaf)
{
    if (leaf->value == key)
    {
        cout << "failed inserting node: duplicate item" << endl;
        return;
    }
    else if (leaf->value < key)
    {
        if (leaf->right != NULL) insert(key, leaf->right);
        else
        {
            TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode;
            newNode->left = NULL;
            newNode->right = NULL;
            newNode->value = key;
            leaf->right = newNode;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (leaf->left != NULL) insert(key, leaf->left);
        else
        {
            TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode;
            newNode->left = NULL;
            newNode->right = NULL;
            newNode->value = key;
            leaf->left = newNode;
        }
    }
};

template <class T>
BST<T>::TreeNode* BST<T>::search(T key, TreeNode* leaf)
{
    if (leaf == NULL) return NULL;
    if (leaf->value == key) return leaf;
    else if (leaf->vluae < key) return search(key, leaf->right);
    else return search(key, leaf->left);
};

template <class T>
void printInOrder(TreeNode* leaf)
{
    if (leaf->left != NULL) printInOrder(leaf->left);
    cout << leaf->value << " ";
    if (leaf->right != NULL) printInOrder(leaf->right);
};

template <class T>
void printPreOrder(TreeNode* leaf)
{
    cout << leaf->value << " ";
    if (leaf->left != NULL) printPreOrder(leaf->left);
    if (leaf->right != NULL) printPreOrder(leaf->right);
};

template <class T>
void printPostOrder(TreeNode* leaf)
{
    if (leaf->left != NULL) printPostOrder(leaf->left);
    if (leaf->right != NULL) printPostOrder(leaf->right);
    cout << leaf->value << " ";
};

template <class T>
void BST<T>::insert(int key)
{
    if (this->root == NULL)
    {
        this->root = new TreeNode;
        this->root->left = NULL;
        this->root->right = NULL;
        this->root->value = key;
    }
    else insert(key, root);
};

template <class T>
BST<T>::TreeNode* BST<T>::search(int key)
{
    search(key, this->root);
};

template <class T>
void BST<T>::printTree(int option)
{
    switch (option)
    {
    case BST<T>::INORDER:
        printInOrder(this->root);
        cout << endl;
        break;
    case BST<T>::POSTORDER:
        printPostOrder(this->root);
        cout << endl;
        break;
    case BST<T>::PREORDER:
        printPreOrder(this->root);
        cout << endl;
        break;
    }
};

template <class T>
void BST<T>::destroyTree()
{
    destroyTree(this->root);
};

#endif
```

As you can see, for the `void insert(T key, BST<T>::TreeNode* leaf)` and `BST<T>::TreeNode* BST<T>::search(T key, TreeNode* leaf)` functions I need to do things with `TreeNode` class like returning an object of it or passing it to a function, which is a nested type defined in class `BST`.
The errors I am getting are at syntax errors, but I don't know where I am doing wrong in the code.
Any advice or suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: A bunch of missing `BST<T>::`s, to start with. The `search` functions also need a `typename` in front.

Comment: "The errors I am getting are at syntax errors, but I don't know where I am doing wrong in the code." The errors certainly contain this information. But for us to be able to use this info, you need to post the errors.

Comment: The syntax error for the insert function is `syntax error: identifier 'TreeNode'`.

Answer (score 2):

You should:

- replace every single `TreeNode` by `BST<T>::TreeNode`, because there could be different `TreeNode` definitions so the compiler need to know the one you are talking about.
- add `typename` in front of every `BST<T>::TreeNode`. There could be several different definitions for `BST<T>::TreeNode`, even some that are not types, so you need to tell the compiler that it is a type.

Comment: No `typename` requires a qualified name.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad, `BST<T>` is the required qualified name. Sorry for the mistake :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you please elaborate more on the typename keyword? I am a little confused as when is it necessary to use it. Also, after fixing the syntax errors, I'm getting a lot of link errors which I can't read... they are something like `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __thiscall BST<int>::printPreOrder(struct BST<int>::TreeNode *)" (?printPreOrder@?$BST@H@@AAEXPAUTreeNode@1@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall BST<int>::printTree(int)" (?printTree@?$BST@H@@QAEXH@Z)`

Comment: When you have a nested symbol (like `TreeNode`) in a template, it is almost impossible for the compiler to determine what is the nature of the symbol: think of a definition of a nested variable called `TreeNode`! As template definitions can be sensitive to the template parameters, it is impossible to determine the real nature of a symbol. So if you use it as a type you should claim it so. This is basically the purpose of `typename` (i.e. "the next word IS a type, believe me for the moment!").

Comment: You should qualify your `printPreOrder` definition like in `BST<T>::printPreOrder`. f not you are defining a function named `printPreOrder` not a method `printPreOrder` of the class `BST<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class BST
{
    struct TreeNode {
        TreeNode* left;
        TreeNode* right;
        T value;
    };

    //member functions
    void destroyTree(TreeNode* leaf);
    void insert(T key, TreeNode* leaf);
    TreeNode* search(T key, TreeNode* leaf);
    void printInOrder(TreeNode* leaf);
    void printPreOrder(TreeNode* leaf);
    void printPostOrder(TreeNode* leaf);

    //memebr variables
    TreeNode* root;
public:

    enum Traversal { INORDER, PREORDER, POSTORDER };
    BST();
    BST(T key);
    ~BST();

    void insert(T key);
    TreeNode* search(T key);
    void printTree(T option);
    void destroyTree();
};

template <class T>
BST<T>::BST()
{
    root = NULL;
};

template <class T>
BST<T>::BST(T key)
{
    root = new TreeNode;
    root->left = NULL;
    root->right = NULL;
    root->value = key;
};

template <class T>
BST<T>::~BST()
{
    destroyTree();
};

template <class T>
void BST<T>::destroyTree(TreeNode* leaf)
{
    if (leaf->left != NULL) destroyTree(leaf->left);
    if (leaf->right != NULL) destroyTree(leaf->right);
    delete leaf;
    leaf = nullptr;
};

template <class T>
void BST<T>::insert(T key, typename BST<T>::TreeNode* leaf)
{
    if (leaf->value == key)
    {
        cout << "failed inserting node: duplicate item" << endl;
        return;
    }
    else if (leaf->value < key)
    {
        if (leaf->right != NULL) insert(key, leaf->right);
        else
        {
            BST<T>::TreeNode* newNode = new TreeNode;
            newNode->left = NULL;
            newNode->right = NULL;
            newNode->value = key;
            leaf->right = newNode;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (leaf->left != NULL) insert(key, leaf->left);
        else
        {
            BST<T>::TreeNode* newNode = new TreeNode;
            newNode->left = NULL;
            newNode->right = NULL;
            newNode->value = key;
            leaf->left = newNode;
        }
    }
};

template <class T>
typename BST<T>::TreeNode* BST<T>::search(T key, typename BST<T>::TreeNode* leaf)
{
    if (leaf == NULL) return NULL;
    if (leaf->value == key) return leaf;
    else if (leaf->vluae < key) return search(key, leaf->right);
    else return search(key, leaf->left);
};

template <class T>
void printInOrder(typename BST<T>::TreeNode* leaf)
{
    if (leaf->left != NULL) printInOrder(leaf->left);
    cout << leaf->value << " ";
    if (leaf->right != NULL) printInOrder(leaf->right);
};

template <class T>
void printPreOrder(typename BST<T>::TreeNode* leaf)
{
    cout << leaf->value << " ";
    if (leaf->left != NULL) printPreOrder(leaf->left);
    if (leaf->right != NULL) printPreOrder(leaf->right);
};

template <class T>
void printPostOrder(typename BST<T>::TreeNode* leaf)
{
    if (leaf->left != NULL) printPostOrder(leaf->left);
    if (leaf->right != NULL) printPostOrder(leaf->right);
    cout << leaf->value << " ";
};

template <class T>
void BST<T>::insert(T key)
{
    if (this->root == NULL)
    {
        this->root = new TreeNode;
        this->root->left = NULL;
        this->root->right = NULL;
        this->root->value = key;
    }
    else insert(key, root);
};

template <class T>
typename BST<T>::TreeNode* BST<T>::search(T key)
{
    search(key, this->root);
};

template <class T>
void BST<T>::printTree(T option)
{
    switch (option)
    {
        case BST<T>::INORDER:
            printInOrder(this->root);
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case BST<T>::POSTORDER:
            printPostOrder(this->root);
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case BST<T>::PREORDER:
            printPreOrder(this->root);
            cout << endl;
            break;
    }
};

template <class T>
void BST<T>::destroyTree()
{
    destroyTree(this->root);
};
```

Should work now, but was full of small mistakes like:
`TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode;`,
`template <class T> void insert` instead of `template <class T> void BST<T>::insert`